# condition to check user input

Tags: c

I need a condition for a do-while loop that means the loop is repeated (asking user to enter data again) until it is an integer number and between 1 and 25.

```
while (!isdigit(data) || data < 1 || data > 25);
```

This just throws out a runtime error and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
do {

   /* Read from input and store it in data */

} while( !isdigit(data) || !( data > 1 && data < 25 ) );
```

Comment: Thanks. The checking that the number is >1 and <25 works but if I put a letter in it will continue